# Create a batch file to create multiple folders within many folders

Tags: batch-file, directory

I am trying to create a batch file which will create folders within all sub-folders of a given folder. So for example if it ran in the directory C:\Example, it would create a folder a, b, and c under each of the 20 folders regardless of their name.

It would be much easier to do this automatically rather than copy the .bat file to every individual folder to create the 5 same folders every time with just md.

So far everything I have created has been a disaster, so I'm hoping someone can help me out with this.

Comment: Some notes on what you have tried and what exactly didn't work would be much appreciated.

Comment: Honestly Joey I only know how to do very basic batch commands, and all I really had was something along the lines of 'md 1 md 2 md 3' etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for /d %%x in (*) do mkdir "%%x\a" "%%x\b" "%%x\c"
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, any idea why it is only working for about 1/3 of the folders?

Comment: I think what's happening is every folder name that contains a comma, it abbreviates the name, creates a new folder and puts the needed new folders in there. Is this something that can be resolved or will these commas foil everything?